# Nginx: Setting up SSL-passthorugh

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to configure SSL-passthrough for multiple webapps using the same nginx server (nginx version: nginx/1.13.6), but when restarting the nginx server, I get an error complaining that

> nginx: [emerg] "stream" directive is duplicate

The configuration I have is the following:

2 files for the ssl passthrough that look like this:

server1.conf:

```
stream {
    upstream workers {
            server 192.168.1.10:443;
            server 192.168.1.11:443;
            server 192.168.1.12:443;
        }

    server {
        listen server1.com:8443;
        proxy_pass workers;
    }
}
```

and server2.conf:

```
stream {
    upstream workers {
            server 192.168.1.20:443;
            server 192.168.1.21:443;
            server 192.168.1.22:443;
        }

    server {
        listen server2.com:8443;
        proxy_pass workers;
    }
}
```

If I remove one of the two files, then nginx starts correctly.

How can this be achieved?

Thanks,
Cristi

Comment: See this [example configuration](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html#example).

Answer (score 0):

Streams work on Layer 5, and cannot read encrypted traffic (which is Layer 6 on the OSI model), and thus cannot tell apart requests hitting `server1.com` and `server2.com` unless they are pointing to different IPs.

This can be solved by one of the following solutions

1. Decrypt the traffic on nginx, then proxy-pass it to backend processes/wockers using HTTP.
2. Bind `server1.com` to a port that is different to `server2.com`.
3. Get an additional IP address and bind `server2.com` on that.
4. Get an additional load balancer and move `server2.com` there.

Comment: Option 1 is not appropriate, as we really want to terminate the SSL at the webserver side, not nginx. Options 4 and 2 are also not appropriate, as setting up a separate load balancer for each web-server would lead to an explosion of lad balancers (no of environments x number of web applications). I would be interested to learn more about option 3. Would this option allow me to have only one nginx server?  How would the configuration for it look like?

Comment: You buy extra IP addresses from your hosting provider, point your DNS record of `server2.com` and everything nginx remains unchanged. The point is, you can't automatically detect which host the client wants to access without different ports/IPs because nginx can't read encrypted traffic you didn't decrypt.

Comment: But doeasn't having multiple IPs mean that I will have multiple nginx instances running?

Comment: Nope, listening to multiple addresses doesn't mean having more than 1 nginx instance running. If that was your concern option 2 may also be a viable solution, and also, free.

Comment: I just didn't want to have one port (or IP address) for each web app, as we have several of them and also many environments in which we deploy those applications (environments that we create dynamically, e.g. when each developer wants to test/demo its changes). But, I understand your point, as long as the traffic is received on one IP:port combination there is no way of deciding to which server to forward it if you don't examine the request itself. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Nevertheless, there is one thing missing: if I have two IPs, how do I configure one nginx instance to listen on both of them? As I described in the issue, in the configuration above nginx doesn't start.

Comment: Oh, if `server1.com` and `server2.com` are already pointing to different IP addresses, then manually entering the IP address (ie. `127.0.0.1` and `127.0.0.2`) should suffice. And to listen on both `0.0.0.0` (all) should do.